# Vlookup Not working on text between two tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is not your average vlookup error.

I have two Power Query tables that I've setup. One is coming from a CSV file with a list of names. The other is from a website pulling a list of names.

i.e. 
=John Smith = John Smith would not be true for some reason.

They vlookup should be able to find the name easily. I've tried proper,upper, clean, trimming and text to columns and everything else that I could think of. I've changed data types to no avail.

I know that one query is causing the issue. I can type the name exactly and do a vlookup from one, and it works. The second query that I do this to doesn't return anything on the typed text.

Anyone encounter this issue while using Power Query?

EDIT: See Jeeped's Answer - When I replace the space from the web query with a normal space it works.

Comment: Assuming you have already trimmed off leading and trailing spaces, one of the **John Smith** entries (likely the one from the web) uses a non-breaking space (e.e. CHAR(160) or ASCII 0×A0) instead of a regular space (e.g CHAR(32) or ASCII 0×20). Use `=CODE(MID(A$1, ROW(1:1), 1))` on both, fill down to get a ASCII code for each letter and compare the numbers.

Comment: I'm confused - PQ doesn't have a Vlookup function?  The equivalent would be a Merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeeped's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581881/vlookup-not-working-on-text-between-two-tables#comment62651343_37581881) has a good answer:

Assuming you have already trimmed off leading and trailing spaces, one of the **John Smith** entries (likely the one from the web) uses a non-breaking space (e.e. CHAR(160) or ASCII 0×A0) instead of a regular space (e.g CHAR(32) or ASCII 0×20). Use

```
=CODE(MID(A$1, ROW(1:1), 1))
```

on both, fill down to get a ASCII code for each letter and compare the numbers.

Comment: This was definitely it, it returned code 160 instead of the 32 like it should have. I was able to go in and replace it in powerquery - then the rest of my lookups worked.